# Open content health tips that I can embed in my app/website

Tags: data-request, api, food

I am looking for open-source or publicly-available health tips for my app. I am so far not successful in finding any thing alike.

Example of a health tip:

> **Title**: Carrots are good for your health
>   **Body**: Did you know that carrots get their bright orange color from β-carotene? α and β-carotenes are partly metabolized into vitamin A, providing more than 100% of the Daily Value (DV) per 100 g serving of carrots.
>   **License**: CC-BY-SA-3.0

JSON format would be ideal, but other formats are OK too.

Comment: What would the ideal structure for these tips be? Open data is most feasible when there's a common understanding of how to model the field the data describes. "Health tips" are very subjective.

Have you seen an application which treats "health tips" as data? If so, perhaps they can be scraped from it, creating de facto open data.

Comment: I am also looking for the same api, were you able to find it? any success?
would be great if you can share it thanks in advance